# DB::query get the date form database only if the date is in future

Tags: laravel-5

In Laravel 5 i have in controller db query which fetch all records from database. Records in MySQL are in date type such as 2017-05-01.

Now I have query
`$dates = DB::table('dates')->get();` but I need get only dates which is in future.

The name of column is date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `where` expression with `>=` operator like below:

```
DB::table('dates')
            ->where('date' , '>=' , Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())->get();
```

Comment: Carbon::now() give the date with time

Comment: `DB::table('dates')->where('date' , '>=' , Carbon::today()->toDateString())->get();` is what I need